# Why isn't my float packing properly?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a site which I am building. How do I select an element and make it float as much up followed by left? I have an item called contact info which is supposed to move to the left as much as possible underneath the header. My next element linklist was supposed to pack itself right next to contact info but for some reason is not doing this. I checked the sizing and they are perfectly fine so I cannot understand why it doesn't float up?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        A2A Luxury Taxi and Limousine <!-- background image: https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2872/12055654844_ab91e2606a.jpg -->
    </div>


    <div id = "contactinfo"> 
        <h3> Contact Us 24/7 At: </h3> 

        908-800-4727

        120 Stryker Lane, Suite 302A, Hillsborough Township NJ
    </div>

    <div id = "linklist">
        <ul>
            <li> Hours and Rates </li>
            <li> Areas of Operations </li>
            <li> About us </li>
            <li> References </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And the corresponding CSS

```
...
#contactinfo
{
    background-image: url("..\\Images and Multimedia\\Images\\fusion2.jpg"); 
    box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0.2em rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    color:white;
    max-width:10em;
    float-left;
}
#linklist
{
    float:left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    max-width: 45em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.5); 
    padding-left:0;
}
```

I am sort of surprised that I can't figure out anything to tinker with and fix. Everything is making sense except the float.

Answer (score 1):

in contactInfo class definition, you have:

```
float-left;
```

instead of

```
float:left;
```

Comment: It seems I run into the problem of assuming I have a logic error as opposed to silly syntax error much more than I would like. Is there some type of "HTML, CSS" debugger out there that can check quickly for incorrect syntax?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas You can always check your code here http://validator.w3.org/ or for example in chrome/firefox on developer tools, you'll see that the wrong property or typos will get cut or have a exclamation point on them

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code:

```
#contactinfo
{
    background-image: url("..\\Images and Multimedia\\Images\\fusion2.jpg"); 
    box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0.2em rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    color:white;
    max-width:10em;
    float-left; /*<--Not good*/
}
```

It should be:

```
#contactinfo
{
    background-image: url("..\\Images and Multimedia\\Images\\fusion2.jpg"); 
    box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0.2em rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    color:white;
    max-width:10em;
    float: left; /*<-- Yay!*/
}
```

You should be good to go after this